# Attribute Error: 'str' object has no attribute 'port'

Tags: python

I tried to run this code but it didn't work
Can someone help me with this?

```
import socket
import sys
try:
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    print "The socket was created succesfully"
except socket.error as err:
    print "The creation of the socket failed due to error %s" %(err)
port = 80
try:
    host_ip = socket.gethostbyname('www.adress.com')
except socket.gaierror:
    print "An error occured while resolving the host"
    sys.exit()
s.connect((host_ip.port))
print "Succesfully connected to adress\
on port == %s" %(host_ip)
```

Comment: The issue is that `host_ip` is a string and does not have an attribute port.
If you want to connect on the port 80 of 'www.adress.com', `s.connect((host_ip.port))` should be `s.connect((host_ip, port))`

Comment: No problem, have a good day.